# Covariance between sample mean and sample standard deviation

Tags: variance, mean, covariance

I am trying to figure out the covariance between sample mean and sample standard deviation. The only related post I can find here is this: [asymptotic covariance between mean and standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122284/asymptotic-covariance-between-mean-and-standard-deviation) and there is no definite answer to it.

A related post is about the covariance between sample mean and sample variance, which I mistakenly posted here while what I truly meant was the covariance between sample mean and sample standard deviation. I am adding the link to the post about the covariance between sample mean and sample variance here in case anyone is looking for the solution: [Covariance between sample mean and sample variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/624632/covariance-between-sample-mean-and-sample-variance?noredirect=1#comment1164098_624632)

Back to my question, I am trying to find $$Cov[\bar{y}, s] = E[\bar{y}s] - E[\bar{y}]E[s]$$.

By linearity of expectation, $$E[\bar{y}] = \mu$$ where $\mu$ is the population mean. By First Order Delta method, $$E[s] = \sigma$$ where $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation. However, I have no idea how to find $E[\bar{y}s]$.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: $E[\bar y]=\mu$ by virtue of linearity of expectation: it doesn't require CLT.  Since you're looking for asymptotics, then the first post you reference asks the same question, doesn't it?  The question itself contains an answer and merely asks whether there is another way to arrive at that answer.

Comment: Hi Whuber, I am not sure if I understand you. I am looking for the way of finding $E[\bar{y}s]$ and consequently finding $Cov[\bar{y}, s]$. The first post I reference asks the same question but there does not seem to have an answer.

Comment: That's *exactly* what the referenced post is asking and (asymptotically) answering.  You imply that you are interested in the asymptotic solution by writing "$E[s]=\sigma,$" which is never true except when $\sigma=0.$  The answer to that post is in the post itself.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in the asymptotic solution, but the reference post does not have an answer.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I thought the OP of the post has never confirmed that his analysis was correct.

Comment: Hi Whuber, I have double checked that https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122284/asymptotic-covariance-between-mean-and-standard-deviation does not have a solution. The solution in the post right now is not correct because the op mistakenly used variance-covariance matrix of sample mean and sample variance. Instead, he should be using the variance covariance matrix of sample mean and sample STANDARD DEVIATION. Therefore, there is still no correct solution to the post.